# Julia, use findall to reset a third row in a 3d array

Tags: arrays, julia, findall

I'm attempting to use `findall` to get an index of which elements of one 1d array are greater than those of a second 1d array, and then use those indexes to set corresponding values of a third 1d array to 0.
MWE:

```
# create 3d array
a, b = [3;2;2], [4;3;2];
c = transpose(cat(a,b, dims = 2));
d, e = [1;2;3], [2;3;4];
f = transpose(cat(d,e, dims = 2));
g = cat(c, f, dims = 3);

g
2×3×2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 3  2  2
 4  3  2

[:, :, 2] =
 1  2  3
 2  3  4

findall.(g[end,:,1] >= g[end-1,:,1])
```

and use indexes to reset elements of g[end,:,2] such that I end up with

```
g
2×3×2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 3  2  2
 4  3  2

[:, :, 2] =
 1  2  3
 0  0  4
```

Thx. J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below gives the answer you request. You just have the `.` in the wrong spot. You want to compare the `>` operation element by element, and then apply `findall` to the entire resulting array (not element by element).

```
julia> g[end, findall(g[end,:,1] .> g[end-1,:,1]), 2] .= 0
2-element view(::Array{Int64,3}, 2, [1, 2], 2) with eltype Int64:
 0
 0

julia> g
2×3×2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 3  2  2
 4  3  2

[:, :, 2] =
 1  2  3
 0  0  4
```

However, I wouldn't try to compile all your data into one big array like that. It would be easier to use three separate 1D array variables than three dimensions in one variable. Again using your variables above:

```
julia> e[b .> a] .= 0
2-element view(::Array{Int64,1}, [1, 2]) with eltype Int64:
 0
 0

julia> e
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 0
 0
 4
```

Comment: Thx. Nathan.  I take your point, in the actual model the data is already in a 3d array, where the size of dim 3 is 5.  Would it be better to use 5, 2d arrays?

Comment: The best storage method is whatever clearly represents the data. You might also consider an array of arrays accessed like `A[5][1,1]`. I might go this route if you have 5 sets of 2D data. Another option would be to create your own data type using the `struct` keyword, which is easier than it sounds. Then you can access `field`s of your type by name. I would personally only use a 3D array if storing data from 3D space, otherwise it becomes difficult to remember what is stored in each direction. You can do it, it just becomes messy and difficult to come back to.